# In Emacs, how to search from beginning of file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs, how I can I instruct `isearch-forward` to search not from the location of the point, but from the beginning of the file?

Comment: I'm pretty certain there was a question a couple of weeks ago exactly like this one. I can't find it right now, but their answer was a little better (it supported C-g and push-mark).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option is to just move the point to the beginning of file with <kbd>M-<</kbd> before invoking isearch. Or, you can write a command that does it for you:

```
(defun isearch-from-buffer-start ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (isearch-forward))
(global-set-key [(control s)] 'isearch-from-buffer-start)
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to make it dump me back out to the place I started from when I `C-g` back out of the search?

Comment: I never use `C-g`, but I do rely on the fact that `isearch` pushes the mark to the previous location of point, which means I can use `C-x C-x` or `C-u C-SPC` to restore the point to the previous location(s). Adding a `(push-mark)` before the `goto-char` invocation would do the same here.

Comment: I added (push-mark) to it but I still don't get the desired behavior, with C-g, with C-x C-x, or with C-u C-SPC.

Comment: @PeterSalazar You need to press `C-u C-SPC` twice. Since isearch itself pushes the mark, the first press returns you to the beginning of buffer (remembered by isearch) and the second one once to your original location.

Comment: Yes! Pressing C-u C-SPC twice works! Any way to assign that to a key binding that isn't four keystrokes long? Thank you!

Comment: You can `global-set-key` a string to another string, but hardcoding *two* `C-u C-SPC` doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: @PeterSalazar `C-u SPC` is intended as a feature to pop the mark off the mark stack. Each user-initiated command that moves the cursor to a faraway location, such as `C-s` or `M-<`, is supposed to leave the mark at the previous location, and `C-u C-SPC` moves back along the breadcrumb trail of marks. A command that pushes **two** marks, as your modified `isearch-from-buffer-start` does, is downright buggy. A command that pops the mark twice is completely useless for anything other than this specific command, and this is why it's not the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging, I've got to the following solution, that seams to work. It's kind of ugly, because it almost manually replaces internal `isearch-cancel` function.

```lisp
(defun isearch-cancel--override ()
  "Terminate the search and go back to the starting point."
  (interactive)
  (if (and isearch-push-state-function isearch-cmds)
      ;; For defined push-state function, restore the first state.
      ;; This calls pop-state function and restores original point.
      (let ((isearch-cmds (last isearch-cmds)))
    (isearch--set-state (car isearch-cmds)))
    (goto-char isearch-opoint))
  (isearch-done t)                      ; Exit isearch..
  (isearch-clean-overlays)
  ;; ----------- this was added: --------------
  (when (and (boundp 'isearch-BOF) isearch-BOF)
    (pop-mark)
    (setq isearch-BOF nil))
  ;; ------------------------------------------
  (signal 'quit nil))                   ; ..and pass on quit signal.

(defun isearch-exit--after ()
  (when (and (boundp 'isearch-BOF) isearch-BOF)
    (pop-mark)
    (setq isearch-BOF nil)))

(advice-add 'isearch-cancel :override 'isearch-cancel--override)
(advice-add 'isearch-exit :after 'isearch-exit--after)

(defun isearch-BOF ()
  (interactive)
  (push-mark)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (setq isearch-BOF t)
  (isearch-forward nil t))
```

Because `isearch-cancel` sends `quit` signal in the end, you can't add any logic after this function (you'll exit all callstack immediately after signal). Trying to ignore this signal doesn't seam to work for me also (not sure why). So I've ended up using copy-pasting technique and adding some lines :)